# Using class.ForName to load ucanaccess in a maven project

Tags: java, maven

Using class.ForName to load ucanaccess in a maven project

OK so I am now totally out of my depth. Everything was going so well before I started to use Maven and now its so much more complicated. 
Anyway I am trying to connect to a database using ucanaccess.

```
public Statement ConnectorNoInsert(String HospNum,String SName,String FName,String DOB) throws SQLException{
        Preferences userPrefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(main.java.Console.TBB_SQLBuilder.class);
        String connectDB ="jdbc:ucanaccess://"+userPrefs.get("PathForDB", null);
        System.out.println("Connection To Database Made  "+userPrefs.get("PathForDB", null));
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(connectDB);
        Statement st =conn.createStatement();   
        return st;
```

The error that I get is:

```
ERROR: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:ucanaccess://PhysJava/Physiology.mdb
```

so I added `Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");` above the `Connection conn` line. This gives me the error:

```
unreported exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown and the project doesnt compile
```

I suppose the question is: how to call `Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");` in a maven project. If I need to use a `ClassLoader` could someone please show me how

Answer (score 0):

The first one ("No suitable driver") is a run-time error, the second one ("unreported exception") a compile-time one. The error message is pretty explicit: "...must be caught or declared to be thrown..." Fix the code in this sense.

Comment: That won't fix the underlying issue which is that it doesn't connect to the database.